# cardano's method in c++

Tags: c++

i am trying to make a program that will compute for the root of a cubic function using cardano's method

here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a, b, c, d, value;
    double f, g, h;
    double i, j, k, l, m, n, p, po;
    double r, s, t, u;
    double x1, x2, x2re, x2im, x3re, x3im, x3;

    cin >> value;
    for(int w=1; w <= value; w++){
       cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
       cout << "CUBIC EQUATION : " << a << " x^3 + " << b << " x^2 + " << c <<" x + " << d << " = 0" << endl;

       f = ((3*c/a)-((b*b)/(a*a)))/3;
       g = ((2*(b*b*b)/(a*a*a))-(9*b*c/(a*a))+(27*d/a))/27;   
       h = ((g*g)/4)+((f*f*f)/27);


    if(f==0 && g==0 && h==0){     // all roots are real and equal
       x1 = pow((d/a),0.33333333333333333333333333333333);
       x2 = pow((d/a),0.33333333333333333333333333333333);
       x3 = pow((d/a),0.33333333333333333333333333333333);
       cout << "x = " << x1 << endl;
       cout << "x = " << x2 << endl;
       cout << "x = " << x3 << endl;
       }
    else if(h<=0){         // all 3 roots are real
       i = pow((((g*g)/4)-h),0.5);
       j = pow(i,0.33333333333333333333333333333333);
       k = acos((g/(2*i))*-1);
       l = j * -1;
       m = cos(k/3);
       n = sqrt(3) * sin(k/3);
       p = (b/(3*a))*-1;
       x1 = (2*j)*m-(b/(3*a));
       cout << "x = " << x1 << endl;
       x2 = l * (m+n) + p;
       cout << "x = " << x2 << endl;
       x3 = l * (m-n) + p;
       cout << "x = " << x3 << endl;
       }
    else if(h>0){
       r = ((g/2)*-1)+pow(h,0.5);
       s = pow(r,0.33333333333333333333333333333333);
       t = ((g/2)*-1)-pow(h,0.5);
       u = pow((t),0.33333333333333333333333333333333);
       x1 = (s+u) - (b/(3*a));
       cout << "x = " << x1 << endl;
       x2re = (((s+u)*-1)/2) - (b/(3*a));
       x2im = -(s-u)*pow(3,0.5)/2;
       cout << "x = (" << x2re << "," << x2im << ")" << endl;
       x3re = (((s+u)*-1)/2) - (b/(3*a));
       x3im = (s-u)*pow(3,0.5)/2;
       cout << "x = (" << x3re << "," << x3im << ")" << endl;
       }
       }

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone help implement a user-defined ComplexNumber in this code?
I want to use this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function but i cant understand this.

Comment: Complex number? Like the one that [already exist in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)? Or some other kind of "complex number"?

Comment: i need to define a user-defined Complex Number

Answer (score 3):

> can anyone help implement a user-defined ComplexNumber in this code?

Don't implement a user-defined ComplexNumber type. Use the one provided by the language. Just `#include <complex>`. With that you can have a complex variable simply by `complex<double> variable_name`.

**Code comments:**

1. It's better to use `std::sqrt(x)` rather than `std::pow(x, 0.5)`.
2. If you are on a POSIX-compliant machine, your math library has a cube root function, cbrt(double) in the header . (It may not be exported to the C++ header .) This too is preferable over `std::pow(x,0.33333333333333333333333333333333)`.

Comment: i am not allowed to use that and i also want to learn how to make a user-defined functions.
I am just a newbie in this programming language